# DotNetOpenAuth entityframework

Tags: asp.net, facebook, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, dotnetopenauth

Ok,  gurus, here is my issue.

I have a asp.net VB project created in visual studio 2012. For simplicity I created a new project.

I added my facebook api information (For authentication)

Facebook authentication works.

I used the NuGet interface to update openAuth.  Facebook authentication still worked.

I used NuGet to update entityframework (It doesn't matter what version I upgrade to) and dotnet open auth no longer works.  My issue is a runtime error while the registerexternallogin.aspx checks whether or not the local use is logged in.  This is the line of code in registerExternalLogin.aspx (created by visual studio automatically with the project)

```
  ' User has logged in with provider successfully
    ' Check if user is already registered locally
    If OpenAuth.Login(authResult.Provider, authResult.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie:=False) Then
        RedirectToReturnUrl()
    End If
```

Stack Trace:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuthDataProvider.GetUserNameFromOpenAuth(String openAuthProvider, String openAuthId) +51
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.Login(String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +66
   Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth.OpenAuth.Login(String providerName, String providerUserId, Boolean createPersistentCookie) +197
   Account_RegisterExternalLogin.ProcessProviderResult() +588
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3177

Specifying my runtime to use entityframework 5.0.x does not fix the issue (In this case it was upgrade to 6) and rolling back entityframework using the command line does not fix the issue.

Thanks in advance.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today after a couple of hours of testing. It was working at first with no problem. I then deleted the user and member from the DB that had previously been created and deleted all site cookies (just in case).

However, the only way I found to overcome the error (no changes to code) was to test again with a another login. (A different Twitter account).

Answer (score 0):

OK, just reverted testing with my original Twitter account and got the error again.

I fixed the error by:

1. Delete the relevant records from tables [aspnet_Users], [aspnet_Membership], [UsersOpenAuthAccounts] and [UsersOpenAuthData].
2. Restart web site on IIS.
3. Delete site cookies.

Problem solved.